# Asking for some exercises to help me understanding abelian varieties better?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I want to study Mumford's Abelian Varieties in the coming winter break. I tried to study it before, but I didn't find my self really understanding(or memorizing) too much. I guess a better and more solid way to learn something is to go over many exercises. So I'm asking for some exercises(or problems?) on abelian varieties, it would be nice if I can get them online. Thanks in advance.

And about the exercises: I wish it would be kind of like the ones in Hartshorne, so that I can solve them if I understand the material well. And not too hard, I guess I'm not looking for some research level questions... Also I wish those exercises may focus more on the algebraic/arithmetic side. I know the description above might seem a little picky, I'd be very appreciated if anyone has any idea or source about this, thanks again in advance...

Comment: There are some in Birkenhake-Lange, although the book is very much focused on the complex analytic case. Conrad has some [homework](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249CS15Page/homework.html) but I'm not sure how easy it will be to do without having been in the class. The book used is Mumford's, though.